# New-DbaConnectionString : The term 'New-DbaConnectionString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I am trying to connect to SQL Server through powershell, when trying to create a SQL instance with the following variable:

```
$sqlInstance = New-DbaConnectionString  -SqlInstance $server -Datbase $database -TrustServerCertificate
```

When I run the script I get the following error:

> New-DbaConnectionString : The term 'New-DbaConnectionString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I can connect to the database with an Invoke-Sqlcmd and it produces the query expected

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $SQL_Command -ServerInstance $server -Database $database
```

I tried looking if I need to install the function / a module as I am also getting the following error when I try and call Import-DbaCsv:

> Import-DbaCsv : The term 'Import-DbaCsv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Have you installed [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/)?

Comment: Thanks, No I hadn't

Comment: If you still haven't here: Install-Module dbatools -Scope CurrentUser